# Can I run a normal tensorflow object detection model on Jetson board without using TensorRT?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, nvidia-jetson, tensorrt, tensorflow-model-garden

Is it possible to run the inference graph on the jetson board without converting it into TensorRT format as mentioned in the [github repo](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/tf_trt_models) ?

Will we be able to run the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) without using TensorRT on the Jetson board?

Answer (score 0):

- Install TF from Nvidia [website](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html) for the right jetpack version.
- Coming to the object detection, execute first code block under Step 1, mentioned in this [link](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-run-tensorflow-object-detection-model-on-jetson-nano/)

```
    git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
    
    apt-get install -qq protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
    
    pip install -q Cython contextlib2 pillow lxml matplotlib
    
    pip install -q pycocotools
    
    cd /content/models/research
    protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
    
    import os
    import sys
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/'
    sys.path.append("/content/models/research/slim/")
    
    python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

- Then follow the steps from this famous [blog](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/creating-your-own-objectdetector) of Gilbert Tanner

**Note**: You might get errors when running the code block as above, or while running the python file as below. Keep fixing every errors, until TF is properly installed.

`python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf1_test.py`

Tensorflow installed and I did inference as well.